# How to (re) use an existent static IP address when creating a TLS Ingress Resource?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm creating an (tls enabled) ingress resource using following configurations:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app-apis
spec:
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret
  backend:
    serviceName: my-web-service
    servicePort: 80
```

A new static IP address is provisioned everytime.
Is it possible to reuse an existent one ?

(I'm using Kubernetes running on GKE)

Comment: what is the command you used to create the resource? GCE/GKE distinguishes 2 types of external IPs: static and ephemeral. Usually if you don't specify it's ephemeral.

Comment: According to the docs when the "tls" setting is used a static IP is provisioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the IP address in an annotation on the Ingress (it looks like you specify it by name rather than IP address). This is only picked up by the GCE controller so don't expect it to work anywhere other than GCE/GKE.

https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/gce/controller/utils.go#L48

Something like this should work:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 name: myingress
 annotations:
   "kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name": my-ip-name
spec:
  ...
```

Comment: Do you know if GCP supports adding a similar annotation to a Service, type:LoadBalancer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed this tutorial for creating ingress object: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer?

If i remember correctly (also I use http not https) I had to assign static IP to GLBc manually:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/globalForwardingRules:

> Value of the reserved IP address that this forwarding rule is serving on behalf of. For global forwarding rules, the address must be a global IP; for regional forwarding rules, the address must live in the same region as the forwarding rule. If left empty (default value), an ephemeral IP from the same scope (global or regional) will be assigned.

Comment: The tutorial now contains a "Step 5: (Optional) Configuring a static IP address" section.